# ListCtrl - wxPython / Python

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

My question is if we can assign/bind some value to a certain item and hide that value(or if we can do the same thing in another way).

Example: Lets say the columns on ListCtrl are "Name" and "Description":

```
self.lc = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
self.lc.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
self.lc.InsertColumn(1, 'Description')
```

And when I add a item I want them to show the Name parameter and the description:

```
num_items = self.lc.GetItemCount()
        self.lc.InsertStringItem(num_items, "Randomname")
        self.lc.SetStringItem(num_items, 1, "Some description here")
```

Now what I want to do is basically assign something to that item that is not shown so I can access later on the app.

So I would like to add something that is not shown on the app but is on the item value like:

```
hiddendescription = "Somerandomthing"
```

Still didn't undestand? Well lets say I add a button to add a item with some other TextCtrls to set the parameters and the TextCtrls parameters are:

"Name"

"Description"

"Hiddendescription"

So then the user fills this textctrls out and clicks the button to create the item, and I basically want only to show the Name and Description and hide the "HiddenDescription" but to do it so I can use it later.

Sorry for explaining more than 1 time on this post but I want to make sure you understand what I pretend to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the wxListCtrl lets you associate arbitrary data with an item, that will not be displayed - read the docs for the following methods:

[SetItemData](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxlistctrl.html#wxlistctrlsetitemdata)

[GetItemData](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxlistctrl.html#wxlistctrlgetitemdata)

[FindItemData](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxlistctrl.html#wxlistctrlfinditem)

The wxListItem class also has GetData and SetData methods.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't let you associate arbitrary data, it lets you associate an integer. This is only useful for 'arbitrary data' if you use [tgray's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2656249/665488).

Comment: @Cam: you are right.  If you need to store an arbitrary python object you need to put it in a dict and store the key.  [This page](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ListControls) on the wxPython wiki has a mixin class that adds a SetPyData method to do this automatically.  It is missing the GetPyData and FindPyData methods, but they are trivial to add.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the ListCtrl as your data structure, you could keep a separate list/dict of objects that contain all the information you want and refresh the ListCtrl from your other data structure.

For example:

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name, description, hidden_description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.hidden_description = hidden_description
```

Then in your application:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.my_items = {}
    self.lc = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
    self.lc.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
    self.lc.InsertColumn(1, 'Description')

def addItemToMyListCtrl(self, name, description, hidden):
    new_item = MyObject(name, description, hidden)
    self.my_items[name] = new_item
    self.lc.Append((new_item.name, new_item.description))
```

Then when you want to use your additional data you can just look up the correct item in the dictionary and your data will be there.

Comment: Didn't think about this, thanks alot, i'll give a try to this method!

Answer (score 1):

You could always set the width of the hidden column to zero, that might accomplish what you want. I just tried it in a C++ (non-wx) program and it worked fine.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help and it would be a good idea if there wasn't a little problem, when I go to resize the Description column it appears to resize either Description column and the hiddendescription column revealing the information... But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`wx.ListCtrl` doesn't let you associate a python object with an item like `wx.TreeCtrl` does with its extremely useful `SetPyData()` method (and corresponding `GetPyData()`).

I haven't tried it myself, but there is code [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ListControls#Python_Data_Mixin) that shows how to create a class to mix in python data with a list. Although I'll admit, it's not clear to me how you're meant to use it.

It also might be possible to directly inherit from wx.ListCtrl, and add the appropriate methods, but I haven't seen any attempts at that anywhere, so it may be harder than I'm thinking.

Alternately you can just use `SetItemData()` to store an int in each item, and use that int to index a dict (or list, if the items are ordered reliably and consistently) that contains the associated objects. tgray has already shown how to do this, and it's listed at the page I link above as well, so I won't go over it again.